# Strings of same length to graph structure

Tags: c, graph

I have a typical problem and looking to solve using **C**. Given an character array `char *buffer[40]` Element in `buffer` can store varying length string. Strings of same length forms a component of a graph. Suppose, if the `buffer` array has 10 strings with length 4 and 30 strings with length 6, i wanted to create two graph components with the following properties.

1. Each node of the graph represents a string
2. An Edge exist between the node only when the string differs in single character

What data structure will be very easy to implement my scenario.
How do we go about meeting the requirement in C?

Comment: This is not a question, this is more like "here's my homework, someone please do it for me". What did you try? Show us some code!

Comment: im not asking for solution. Need to know which data structure to use?